# Show data values in barchart with plot_ly

Tags: r, r-plotly

I'm new to plot_ly, but this barchart  works fine:

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(emo_sum, x=~emotion, y=~count, type="bar", color=~emotion) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title=""), showlegend=FALSE,
         title="Testing plot_ly")
```

Now I'm trying to show the data values above each bar. I found this example 
[How to change axis features in plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189779/how-to-change-axis-features-in-plotly/46195485)

that does it with a fixed set of values but in my case it looks like this:

```
library(plotly)
    p <- plot_ly(emo_sum, x=~emotion, y=~count, type="bar", color=~emotion) %>%
add_text(text=~count, hoverinfo='none', textposition = 'top', showlegend = FALSE, 
        textfont=list(size=20, color="black")) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title=""), showlegend=FALSE,
         title="Testing plot_ly")
```

But it doesn't work

Here is `emo_sum`, I paste it because I cannot attach, for each emotion there's the number of words:

```
            count      emotion
anger          120        anger
anticipation   255 anticipation
disgust         85      disgust
fear           170         fear
joy            201          joy
sadness        121      sadness
surprise       106     surprise
trust          298        trust
negative       270     negative
positive       440     positive
```

Comment: You should provide `emo_sum`, otherwise we can't run your code.

Comment: I pasted it here, i think i cannot attach files..

Comment: If you run `dput(emo_sum)` and print that output in your question, we can rebuild that dataset. Otherwise we would have to rebuild it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work and should plot the text above the bars, but I dont know how your original datset looks like. If there are multiple values per emotion, then there will be more values over one bar. You could then group by emotions and sum the values up and just display that sum.

I included 2 examples for you, the first plots the text inside the bars and the second above the bars:

```
library(plotly)

## Data
emo_sum <- data.frame(
  emotion=sample(c("anger", "joy", "fear", "anticipation", "disgust", "sadness"), 6, F),
  count=trunc(runif(6,0,100))
)

## Plot text inside Bar
plot_ly(emo_sum, x=~emotion, y=~count, type="bar", color=~emotion,
        text = ~count, textposition = 'auto', insidetextfont = list(size=20, color = 'black')) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title=""), showlegend=FALSE,
         title="Testing plot_ly")

## Plot text above Bar
plot_ly(emo_sum, x=~emotion, y=~count, type="bar", color=~emotion) %>%
  add_text(text=~count, hoverinfo='none', textposition = 'top', showlegend = FALSE,
           textfont=list(size=20, color="black")) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title=""), showlegend=FALSE,
         title="Testing plot_ly")
```